# Spock's groovy test fails with ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException at Stub()

Tags: java, groovy, spock

I have a java class `AgentConverter` as which implements
`org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter` -

```
public class AgentConverter implements Converter<RequestWrapper, TicketingAgent> {

    public TicketingAgent convert(RequestWrapper wrapper) {

        TicketingAgent agent = new TicketingAgent();
        ....
        ....
```

Then I have java class which is using above `AgentConverter` as -

```
public class BuildTicketingDocumentRequest implements BuildRequest<TicketingDocumentRequest> {

    private final PosConverter posConverter;
    private final AgentConverter agentConverter;    //here it is ..
    private final TransactionInfoConverter transactionInfoConverter;
    private final BuildRequestComponent<TicketingDocument> buildRequestComponent;
```

I have written Groovy test case where I am stubbing the `AgentConverter` class -

```
class ConversionStrategyForDocCreateTest extends EdiSimulator  {

    def "Master Test for Build Conversion Strategy to create TicketingDocumentRequest"() {

        given:"Mocked Classes"
        AgentConverter agentConverter = Stub(AgentConverter.class)     // this line exception comes 
        agentConverter.convert(wrapper) >> new TicketingAgent()        
        .....
        .....
```

Now when above test case - I am getting:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 45569

    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.BridgeMethodResolver.resolveAll(BridgeMethodResolver.java:61)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.emitMethods(Enhancer.java:911)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.generateClass(Enhancer.java:498)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.DefaultGeneratorStrategy.generate(DefaultGeneratorStrategy.java:25)
    at net.sf.cglib.core.AbstractClassGenerator.create(AbstractClassGenerator.java:216)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createHelper(Enhancer.java:377)
    at net.sf.cglib.proxy.Enhancer.createClass(Enhancer.java:317)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory$CglibMockFactory.createMock(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:91)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.ProxyBasedMockFactory.create(ProxyBasedMockFactory.java:49)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.JavaMockFactory.create(JavaMockFactory.java:51)
    at org.spockframework.mock.runtime.CompositeMockFactory.create(CompositeMockFactory.java:44)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMock(SpecInternals.java:45)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.createMockImpl(SpecInternals.java:281)
    at org.spockframework.lang.SpecInternals.StubImpl(SpecInternals.java:131)
    at com.sabre.ticketing.hub.converter.startegy.ConversionStrategyForDocCreateMasterTest.Master Test for Build Conversion Strategy to create TicketingDocumentRequest(ConversionStrategyForDocCreateMasterTest.groovy:35)
```

While hit & trial I found if I remove AgentConverter's  **implements Converter** like below -

```
public class AgentConverter {             // Here i have removed "implements Converter"

    public TicketingAgent convert(RequestWrapper wrapper) {

        TicketingAgent agent = new TicketingAgent();
```

then things start working and there is no `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I am trying to understand what is the relation between `Stub()` in Spock framework AND stubbed class's interface implementation. Couldn't find in google so posted here... Any help is appreciated.

Here is my POM snippet for spock & groovy versions :

```
  <dependency>
       <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
       <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
       <version>1.0-groovy-2.4</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
       <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
       <version>2.4.4</version>
       <scope>test</scope>
   </dependency>
```

Comment: Check your code with Spock 1.3 (or 2.0-M3) and Byte Buddy. Spock 1.0 has been released over 5 years ago. Number of bugs has been fixed since then.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I used spock ~ 1.5 years ago, maybe things have changed since then...

Anyway:

Are you running with Java 9?

If so, check this [cglib issue](https://github.com/cglib/cglib/issues/106):

All-in-all cglib seems to have an issue, you can try to use bytebuddy instead as suggested in this thread.

Another possible solution is refactoring:

Maybe `BuildTicketingDocumentRequest` can depend on interface rather than concrete implementation like `AgentConverter`. When the mock is created out of the interface, it should work.